# Multivariate, One-to-One, $\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, integers

This question is in two parts:

a. One, is it possible to make a bivariate function $f(a,b)$ that is one-to-one (e.g $f(a,b) \neq f(b,a) \neq f(c,d) \neq f(d,c)$ that gives one single number given two integers ($\mathbb{Z}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$)? The function should use operators (floor, $+$, $-$, etc. but not concatenation).

b. Is it possible to extend this function to $k$ variables ($\mathbb{Z}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$)? The same thing should apply to this new function $g$ (one-to-one, operators are allowed, but nothing like concatenation)

Comment: you can use primes numbers $2^a3^b5^c\cdots$

Comment: @zwim That is a good idea, but it grows too large too quickly, I would like to use something that grows slower. Although, because it is technically right, if no one else comes up with something, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use power of primes numbers $2^a3^b5^c\cdots$.

The main advantage is that it generalizes to $\mathbb Z^k$ for any $k$ without issue.
Note also that this is a very recursive approach in that you can then define $2^{2^{a_1}3^{b_1}}3^{2^{a_2}3^{b_2}}$ and this is something which is often used theoretically speaking.

However if you prefer something growing slower (however for negative values of $a,b,c$ above, you get small numbers too...) what about a mapping $\mathbb Z^2\mapsto\mathbb Z$ for instance $f(x,y)=y+\frac 12(x+y-1)(x+y-2)$ followed by a mapping $\mathbb Z\mapsto \mathbb Q$ via the Stern-Brocot tree ?